# Dynamic css from node?

Tags: nodes, theming

I like to implement this codepen into drupal but the images in the background should come from a ctype within Drupal.

The codepen example: 
http://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/myPBNg

So basically how to get this line dynamic in a page?

```
article {
  background: url(https://foo.com/fooimage.jpg) no-repeat center; 
}
```

Can you point me to the good direction? Is there a module which support this? What tags should I look?

Comment: Where do you want to display the background image? on a node page, on the front page,...?

Comment: The background image should come in a node so in the basis I would like to use it as table background property. This node is displayed in a mini-panel which is displayed on a basic page. Also I would like to use it a slider of images and extend it with clickable text on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
// replace this with the url from the node object
$imgURL = 'https://foo.com/fooimage.jpg';
$style  = 'article {';
$style .= 'background: url(' . $img_url . ') no-repeat center;';
$style .= '}';
drupal_add_css($style, array('type' => 'inline'));
```

For the $img_url though you need to fond out how to get the image url. You would need to load the node using node_load() then use dsm() from the Devel module or just use print_r() to display the field array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by the "article" css that you want the background image on the on the markup which wraps the content in a node.tpl.php. You can add the style attribute directly to the attributes array in a [node preprocess](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7). This example also gets the path to a specific image style for control over the image.

This would go in your template.php with the proper names swapped out to pull in your specific image field and image style.

```
/*
 *
 * Override or insert variables into the node templates.
 *
 * @param $variables
 *   An array of variables to pass to the theme template.
 * @param $hook
 *   The name of the template being rendered ("node" in this case.)
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables, $hook) {
  $type = $variables['type'];
  $view_mode = $variables['view_mode'];

  switch ($type) {
    case 'CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME':
      // Ensure we only effect the node page
      if ($view_mode == 'full' && node_is_page($variables['node'])) {

         // Adjust to your specific image field. 
         // This may be different apart from swapping field names. 
         // Use Devel module and dpm($variables); to find your field's uri in the $variables array.
         $field_uri = $variables['FIELD_MACHINE_NAME'][0]['uri'];

        // Assuming you'll have an image style for it. Enter the machine name in here.
        $image_url = image_style_url('IMAGE_STYLE_MACHINE_NAME', $field_uri);
        $variables['attributes_array']['style'] = 'background-image: url(' . $image_url . ');background-repeat: no-repeat;';

      }
      break;
  }
}
```

The `switch` statement is for code readability should you preprocess other node types in the future. Just add another `case` & `break`.